# How can I access wordpress blog posts url when I used stable page as my blog home page?

Tags: wordpress

I chose a single page as home page in my WordPress blog setting, but I want my posts to be visible as well. Is there a url (or any other way) to access the posts list (like the homepage in normal WordPress blogs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.

first add new page to your website.

then go to setting>reading and select that page in post page field

Answer (score 1):

In order to do so, you can use [recent posts widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-extended/) plugin.
This [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJp8Y69Nuss) can help you out (Seek video to 1:00).